# formatting ZonedDateTime.now()

Tags: datetime

```
DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM/dd/yy HH:mmaa").format(ZonedDateTime.now())
```

complains it requires a TemporalAccesor, not a ZonedDateTime.  I am DateTime backport.  ZonedDateTime implements Temporal.  Temporal extends TemporalAccessor.  I expected "03/02/20 02:19PM".

Comment: I don’t think you want `HH:mmaa`. Possibly `hh:mma` (lower case `hh`, only one `a`).

Answer (score 1):

I was using a java formatter, `java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter` but a backport time, `org.threeten.bp.ZonedDateTime`. They don’t work together.

An obvious solution is to import `java.time.ZonedDateTime` instead.

Or if you’ve got specific reasons for using the backport, then `org.threeten.bp.format.DateTimeFormatter`.